# Upload apk on playstore

Tags: android

My previous app apk had a permission of SMS_RECEVIE which is now unpublished from production.
It was done by some other developer so I don't have any details about it.

Now I have uploaded a new apk on beta which do not have any SMS_RECEVIE permission which got rejected.

please suggest me what to do now.

Comment: You received a violence mail from google. Post the screenshot what the issue in the apk.

Comment: Share screenshot shows in playstore console

Comment: Yes if app has any SMS related permission it will be rejected

Comment: Please verify if you are reading sms or call logs. Or you are trying to read these data in your boot complete receiver. Or any third party library is having these permissions are using these sensitive information. I would also suggest you to verify merged manifest file and check what all permission are added there. And share the mail from google as well.

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove SMS permission from manifest if your app requires just reading OTP.
2. Use SMS retriever API
   https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview
3. Google has sent a mail to you regarding this. you might need to submit that form once again.
4. wait for 24 hrs.

Or

Upload a new version of your APK and submit a permissions declaration form to enable further review.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you have already removed the `SMS_RECIEVE` from the app, there should be no more problem with publishing the app.

Just go to play console and publish your new app as a production release. It'll take some time to be published. Anyway if there is not any other violations or issues the app will be published. You can remove your beta release as well.